# adding search option to the select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have two multiselect lists that can interchange the list values with each other by clicking them. I tried to add search functionality to the filled list (select-list) which works fine until the move I click a list element. even though the value is removed from the list still the search option adds that moved element in it. Check the demo(http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/99/).

```
//code is:

//html-
<input id="someinput"><br/>
    <select class="select-cities" name="city" id="optlist" multiple="multiple">
        <option>Frederiksberg</option>
        <option>Vanløse</option>
        <option>Glostrup</option>
        <option>Brøndby</option>
        <option>Roskilde</option>
        <option>Køge</option>
        <option>Gentofte</option>
        <option>Hillerød</option>
        <option>Tårnby</option>
        <option>Vallensbæk</option>
    </select>
</input>
<br/>
<select class="chosen-cities" name="chosen-cities-name" multiple="multiple">
</select>

//jquery:

$(function() { var opts = $('#optlist option').map(function(){
    return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
  });


   $('#someinput').keyup(function(){
     var rxp = new RegExp($('#someinput').val(), 'i');
     var optlist = $('#optlist').empty();
     opts.each(function(){
         if (rxp.test(this[1])) {
             optlist.append($('<option/>').attr('value', this[0]).text(this[1]));
      }
  });

});



    $('.select-cities').click(function () { $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');});

    $('.chosen-cities').click(function () {
    $('.chosen-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.select-cities');
    });

});
  I
```

Comment: I think this is because, you have stored values in `opts` once and then using it always. But you have not removed the items from `opts` which is used in every search.

Comment: How can I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you've cached the values in `opts` once document is loaded and is not updating it when the select gets updated.

You have to re-evaluate `opts` to get the new set of values once an item is moved from the list..

```
$('.select-cities').click(function () {
    $('.select-cities option:selected').remove().appendTo('.chosen-cities');
    opts = $('#optlist option').map(function () {
        return [[this.value, $(this).text()]];
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/100/)

Comment: now it is not even searching the elements which are there in the list

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly, but there is still a problem.
When i again add the value to the list(selected-cities) from chosen cities then the search is not able to search the values

Comment: @Kunal you've to apply the same fix inside both click handlers like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cs6Xb/101/)...

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help.
just one thing that is posing the problem, which you might have missed.
when you perform a search and select a value then the list doesn't show all the values. It is contains only those values which were shown in the search result.
what can be done about it?

Comment: @Kunal That's an issue with the way you're trying to implement it, `var optlist = $('#optlist').empty();` removes the options from the original list, You have them in the cache - until you click something. once you click, the cache will become list of matched elements. You might want to have an array of options, or have a hidden *template dropdown* to get the values back when the search is empty.

Comment: okay sir.
I will try to that.
can any conditional statement prevent it?